# $W$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined as $W = \{(x, y, z)|x + y + z ≥ 1\}$. Is $W$ closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra

$W$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined as  $W = \{(x, y, z)|x + y + z ≥ 1\}$.
(a) Is $W$ closed under vector addition?
If your answer is no, then find two vectors $u, v \in W$ such that $u + v \not\in W$.
(b) Is $W$ closed under scalar multiplication?
If your answer is no, then find a vector $u \in W$ and a scalar $c$ such that $cu \not\in W$.
(c) Is $W$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

I know the answer for a is yes and b is no and c is no
But I do not understand how to get there I have been researching it for a while, but I still do not understand, please help!

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.  Also, please include any work you have done on the problem so that we can see where you are having difficulties.

Comment: It's closed under addition but notice what happens if you multiple (1,1,1) by -1.

Comment: mmmh, if $(x, y, z) \in W$, then $x + y + z \geq 1$, but $-1 * (x, y, z) = (-x, -y, -z)$ doesn't hold the equation. And if you don't like the negative scalar, then search a vector with $x + y + z = 1$ and multiply by 1/2.

Comment: Thanks everyone that helped alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

a) Let $u,v\in W$ where $u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ and $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$. Now we have $u+v=(u_1+v_1,u_2+v_2,u_3+v_3)$. Now what can we say about 
$$(u_1+v_1)+(u_2+v_2)+(u_3+v_3)$$
given that we know $u_1+u_2+u_3\ge1$ and $v_1+v_2+v_3\ge1$?

b) Scalars are just defined as any real number. What happens when we choose $c=0$?

c) Subspaces must be closed under addition and scalar multiplication. You can argue that $W$ is not closed under one of these things from parts a) and b).

Answer (score 0):

No! it is not closed under scalar multiplication. For example let $\lambda=1/2$ and $(x,y,z)\in W$ then $\lambda (x,y,z)\notin W$ and when $\lambda <0$ it is obvious that $W$ is not closed.